# PHP Adhoc Reports and analytics

Tags: php, report, analytics

We are developing project for a research unit. one of their requirement is to analyze on the data they entered. we have our own php module build in where they can create any reports choosing any fields from the db. but the need something flashy. Can any one put me through right direction to find out a good tool for analysis of data

Comment: have your report processing engine spit back xml and the pump that through something like jcharts or highline charts (or even google charts!)

Comment: Hi Dave thanks for Quick reply, we are generating query on the fly and converting the query to tables and jqchart.

Comment: So you want to do further data analysis over and above basic tabling and graphing? Such as ? you may need to store your generated dataset in a memcached or a temp db table of you wish to do anything fancy such as forecasting or historical side by side analysis